# aggregate dataframe based on data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data-frame using a time stamp , In that results are showing every single second, how can I get the aggregation of this data frame as is if data will brought every 60 seconds or 1 minute here is the data-frame

```
structure(list(DATE = c("2013-04-15   02:47:32", "2013-04-15   02:48:02", 
"2013-04-15   02:48:32", "2013-04-15   02:49:02", "2013-04-15   02:49:32", 
"2013-04-15   02:50:02", "2013-04-15   02:50:32", "2013-04-15   02:51:02", 
"2013-04-15   02:51:32", "2013-04-15   02:52:02", "2013-04-15   02:52:32", 
"2013-04-15   02:53:02", "2013-04-15   02:53:32", "2013-04-15   02:54:02", 
"2013-04-15   02:54:32", "2013-04-15   02:55:02", "2013-04-15   02:55:32", 
"2013-04-15   02:56:02", "2013-04-15   02:56:32", "2013-04-15   02:57:02", 
"2013-04-29   17:33:07", "2013-04-29   17:33:37", "2013-04-29   17:34:07", 
"2013-04-29   17:34:37", "2013-04-29   17:35:07", "2013-04-29   17:35:37", 
"2013-04-29   17:36:07", "2013-04-29   17:36:37", "2013-04-29   17:37:07", 
"2013-04-29   17:37:37", "2013-04-29   17:38:07", "2013-04-29   17:38:37", 
"2013-04-29   17:39:07", "2013-04-29   17:39:37", "2013-04-29   17:40:07", 
"2013-04-29   17:40:37", "2013-04-29   17:41:07", "2013-04-29   17:41:37", 
"2013-04-29   17:42:07", "2013-04-29   17:42:37"), Server = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("ServerA", "ServerB"), class = "factor"), 
    CPU = c(70L, 71L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 73L, 73L, 74L, 73L, 73L, 
    73L, 73L, 71L, 74L, 72L, 72L, 70L, 72L, 71L, 70L, 78L, 79L, 
    79L, 78L, 79L, 77L, 78L, 80L, 81L, 80L, 80L, 79L, 79L, 79L, 
    81L, 79L, 78L, 79L, 79L, 79L)), .Names = c("DATE", "Server", 
"CPU")**strong text**
```

I want to use spark SQL and Scala 
Thanks a lot
I want to reduce the size of the data-set 
Thanks a lot

Comment: please share data in reproducible format, this looks like `dput()` from `R`.

Comment: i didn't get your point sorry , did you get what i want ?

Comment: what you shared as dataset cannot be read into spark, so please share it in a format that can.